# Search and add to a list in Scheme

Tags: list, search, scheme, addition

I want to search for an element in a list, like this one (it's a list of lists)

`(name1 (name2 (name3 name4) (name5 (name6))) (name7 (name8 name9)) (name10 (name11 name12)) (name13))`

and when I find that element I want to add to it.
Like search for `name10` and then add a new name to the `name11` and `name12` group.
Any help is much appreciated!

```
(define (adder name2badded indexname treenode)
  (display treenode)
  (newline)
      (cond
        ((null? treenode)#f) ;"Tree is null"))
        ((pair? treenode)
           (if (adder name2badded indexname (car treenode))
             (display "Gotcha!")
           (adder name2badded indexname (cdr treenode))
       )
    ) ;END pair?
    (else
      (eq? indexname treenode)
    );END else
  );END Cond

)
```

This is what I have so far, it will find the spot where I want to add it but I can't get to adding to that spot.

Comment: which programming language ? what have you tried ?

Comment: I have posted my code so far, I just can't figure out how to add, I can find the indexname in the list. I figure I will need to use cons somewhere to add to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must reconstruct the new tree on your way back from the found point, after you've added your new value there. So you must stop one level above where you're stopping now: at `(name old-value ...)` instead of at `name`. This means you must test for equality with `(car treenode)`, not `treenode` itself. This way you'll be able to construct a *new* association group as

```
(cons (car treenode) (cons val2add (cdr treenode)))
```

and you need to alter your recursion structure to use this new updated assoc group instead of the old one, to reconstruct the whole tree on your way back:

```
(define (add-into val2add name tree)
  (if (pair? tree)
    (if (eqv? name (car tree))
      (cons name (cons val2add (cdr tree)))      ; found!
      (cons (add-into val2add name (car tree))   ; it's in CAR or in CDR,
            (add-into val2add name (cdr tree)))) ;   or maybe in both?
    tree))
```

But if your tree were actually an assoc list and you were allowed to use surgical routines, you could just use

```
(define (add-into! val2add name als) 
  (cond ((assv name als) => 
           (lambda (a)
            (set-cdr! a (cons val2add (cdr a)))))))
```

Comment: Ok I see now, great explanation, it makes so much sense.